# Mandrill different message content

Tags: php, email, mandrill

I'm building an application in which I'd like to send e-mails to multiple users. I've read the docs on how to do this (pass an array as recipient) but the problem is that all these users will get the same message content.

My situation is more like this:

- 10 users need to get email with content A
- 55 users need to get email with content B
- 4 users need to get email with content C
- etc

I can imagine two solutions, but I was wondering if someone has experience with this. One is passing a variable for the e-mail content (not sure if this is possible) and the other is for each e-mail content make a new API call (as https://mandrillapp.com/api/docs/messages.php.html) with users grouped in an array for the recipient in that one call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if my answer will be as helpful as it would be if you use SendGrid (considering Mandrill and SendGrid are very similar to each other).

I've been in a situation just like yours, and using SendGrid, I solved send each email individually. Every email had the same template with a different content. Trying to send them in a single call (using an array of recipients) was wrong because it was processed as a single message and all emails were together in the header.

As I could understand from Mandrill's documentation, it might work in the same way as SendGrid, so I recommend you send each email individually.

In my case, here is what I did:

I create a JSON file with a structure like this:

```
{
    "messages": [
        {
            "emails": ["john@doe.com", "foo@bar.com"],
            "content": "Lorem ipsum sit dolor amet"
        },
        {
            "emails": ["john2@doe.com", "foo2@bar.com"],
            "content": "..."
        }
    ]
}
```

*It was a JSON file because I had to fetch the data and build the content first, from a large database, maybe just an array would fulfill your needs*

And Then, I iterated over it calling the API for each single email in each group of messages.

Hope it helps!